# Why is my typing failing when array contains multiple elements but not only one?

Tags: typescript

Given the following code:

```
function SumSystem() {
    return {
        sum(x: number, y: number) {
            return x + y
        }
    }
}

function MultiplySystem() {
    return {
        multiply(x: number, y: number) {
            return x * y
        }
    }
}

function emit<S extends () => Record<string, unknown>>(systems: S[]): { [K in keyof ReturnType<S>]: ReturnType<S>[K] } {
    // whatever
    return {}
}

emit([SumSystem]).sum(1, 2) // works
emit([MultiplySystem]).multiply(2, 2) // works

emit([SumSystem, MultiplySystem]).sum(1, 2) // does not work
emit([SumSystem, MultiplySystem]).multiply(2, 2) // does not work
```

As per comments, the last two `emit`s are not working, and that's occurring because I am passing two values into the argument's array: `[SumSystem, MultiplySystem]`.

Questions:

1. What's the problem?
2. Is it possible to fix it?
3. If the second question is true, how?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZRAW2QTwM5QKZoAUAlIgN4BQi1iATnlCLUpTW4tuoQB4BciYdACM8tADSJM-QWhG1SrdkvqNmibogDUkqksQBfXdUOGKoSLASIAsiAA2sAA53MWXARLkjdBkxbe2NHsnFx5pYVEJKQEI+S89dhU-dUQAKh0EwzYTCjNwaHgkAhgoAB5kRDxufDAAE2xETwBeAD5EACU8CDhaWtLcWhgwAHMJcABrMDgAdzAWlsJsHHw0bH5kAG0AXWJ+MkQNgGlEIcRxvEw4YA7fZgAVTEc8cpat-k7VMAenl6Otg3iNAA9EDENMABYAQ3wADdRN4kmoyDkKMUoIQNqgMMsCDsAHScIgARgkACZSCCwT1xthUWgShjbA4YM5XDi0PigszWYRSWSKaDptTaXSGZj0G4VhImSE2e4OcQCVwSYhyYhKbU4HgGlMoFTaONRejxdj5dLgiyXJLcYqubLefz1aDNdqBHA9UKDUA)

Comment: Small tip: if the definition of a function is not relevant to a problem, you can use `declare function ...` and omit the brackets and body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the generic to infer the type of the entire array instead, get the return type of all the functions, then turn that union into an intersection for the result.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

function emit<S extends (() => Record<string, unknown>)[]>(systems: S): UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<S[number]>> { ... }
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbn38m)

---

Your solution does not work as intended because `S` is inferred as `(() => { sum... }) | (() => { multiply... })` instead of an array.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Also - I reproduced your solution manually, step by step, keeping in mind what you just mentioned for what the problem was and I'd say it was quite simple to spot the issue. Thank you so much for your input!